# How do format text returned by validator

Tags: flutter

I have a `TextFormField` which has a validator which returns a string. I want to show the validation error message in red color and may be some other styling

- How can i change its color?
- Can i configure it in Theme so that i can configure it once for all forms in my app?

**Code**

```
TextFormField(
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
    filled: true,
    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
    hintText: 'First name',
    labelText: 'First Name *',
  ),
  onSaved: (String value) {
    this._customer.fName = value;
  },
  validator: _validateName,
  initialValue: this._customer.fName,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the error color across your whole application override the `theme` property of your `MaterialApp`:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
      // Add this line
      theme: ThemeData(
        errorColor: Colors.yellow,
        hintColor: Colors.yellow,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What about font/color of error msg and hintText and labelText?

Comment: They both use the hintColor property. I've updated my code to add it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the error message font `color` and other properties directly on the `InputDecoration` widget. This allows you to customize each `TextFormField` widget to have different looks such as `color`, `fontSize`, `errorMaxLines` etc.

```
TextFormField(
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        errorStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        errorMaxLines: 2,
        border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
        filled: true,
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        hintText: 'First name',
        labelText: 'First Name *',
    ),
    onSaved: (String value) {
        this._customer.fName = value;
    },
    validator: _validateName,
    initialValue: this._customer.fName,
),
```